# SQL: ORDER BY ASC with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

My SQL query for MySQL db:

```
SELECT `id`, `id_sender`, `id_recipient`, `date_time`, `amount_money`, `id_currency`, `transfer_title`, `authorization_key`, `authorization_status`
FROM `bankapplication_transactions` AS `transaction`
WHERE ((`transaction`.`date_time`
BETWEEN '2019-03-21 08:56:22' AND '2019-04-21 07:56:22'
AND `transaction`.`authorization_status` = 1)
AND (`transaction`.`id_sender` = 3 OR `transaction`.`id_recipient` = 3))
ORDER BY `transaction`.`date_time` ASC
```

My result:

```
id | id_sender | id_recipient | date_time           | ...
2  | 1         | 3            | 2019-04-21 07:51:25 | ...
4  | 4         | 3            | 2019-04-21 07:52:38 | ...
5  | 3         | 4            | 2019-04-21 07:54:39 | ...
```

I would like make a limit of 2, and that he would return the last two results but let it continue to be manipulated with ASC, so I need:

```
id | id_sender | id_recipient | date_time           | ...
4  | 4         | 3            | 2019-04-21 07:52:38 | ...
5  | 3         | 4            | 2019-04-21 07:54:39 | ...
```

I use a Sequelize ORM for NodeJS, so this is my controller:

```
Transaction.findAll({
      where: db.Sequelize.and(
        {
          date_time: {
            [Op.between]: [
              getPreviousMonthDate(getTodayDate()),
              getTodayDate(),
            ],
          },
          authorization_status: setAuthorizationStatus(1),
        },
        db.Sequelize.or({ id_sender: userId }, { id_recipient: userId }),
      ),
      order: [['date_time', 'ASC']],
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you need order by desc and limit 2

```
SELECT `id`, `id_sender`, `id_recipient`, `date_time`, `amount_money`, `id_currency`, `transfer_title`, `authorization_key`, `authorization_status`
FROM `bankapplication_transactions` AS `transaction`
WHERE ((`transaction`.`date_time`
BETWEEN '2019-03-21 08:56:22' AND '2019-04-21 07:56:22'
AND `transaction`.`authorization_status` = 1)
AND (`transaction`.`id_sender` = 3 OR `transaction`.`id_recipient` = 3))
ORDER BY `transaction`.`date_time` desc
lmit 2
```

Comment: @Zanyul, no. I need a ASC, because if I use DESC, it will reverse my results by 180 degrees.

Comment: @reactpromiseprob2 then use subquery and use order by asc like the others answers

Answer (score 0):

You need  a subquery for limit2  and then order by asc

```
 select t.* from  (

  SELECT `id`, `id_sender`, `id_recipient`, `date_time`, `amount_money`, `id_currency`, `transfer_title`, `authorization_key`, `authorization_status`
  FROM `bankapplication_transactions` AS `transaction`
  WHERE ((`transaction`.`date_time`
  BETWEEN '2019-03-21 08:56:22' AND '2019-04-21 07:56:22'
  AND `transaction`.`authorization_status` = 1)
  AND (`transaction`.`id_sender` = 3 OR `transaction`.`id_recipient` = 3))
  ORDER BY `transaction`.`date_time` desc
  lmit 2

  ) t 
  order by transaction`.`date_time` ASC
```

Comment: omg, I use a Sequelize ORM (I edited my post) and I don't know, how can I make this ^

Comment: Change the question make the answer  without sense .. check if you  ORM  can manange raw sql  .. otherwise  your could order the result at presentation level ..